# NXLog Linux - Remove Files After Processing

Tags: nxlog

I am deploying nxlog on a Linux server (Red Hat Enterprise release 6.6). I am currently trying to remove a file after nxlog has finished processing. From the nxlog documentation, I am using file_remove, which is not working. Here is my config that does not throw any syntax errors when starting nxlog. As seen, I used a time interval of every 1 minute as I do not know the best way to have the file deleted after processing. In the debug log, I do not see an attempt to try and match files in the directory for removing:

```
########################################
# Global directives                    #
########################################
User nxlog
Group nxlog

LogFile /var/log/nxlog/nxlog.log
LogLevel DEBUG

########################################
# Modules                              #
########################################
<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Extension fileop>
 Module   xm_fileop
    <Schedule>
        Every   1 min
        Exec    file_remove('/eventarchive/processed/*.raw', (now()));
    </Schedule>
</Extension>

<Input in1>
    Module      im_file
    File        "/eventarchive/processed/*.raw"
    SavePos     TRUE
    #Exec       parse_syslog_bsd();
</Input>

<Output fileout1>
    Module      om_udp
    Host        10.102.103.112
    Port        3333
    Exec        to_syslog_bsd();
</Output>

########################################
# Routes                               #
########################################
<Route 1>
    Path        in1 => fileout1
</Route>
```

I used this same syntax on a Windows setup to test it, which worked; it successfully removed files. On the Linux setup, I have also tried setting a filename instead of "*.raw" but that did not work either. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Does anyone know if there are any limitations with Linux that would stop this from working?

Does anyone know the best way to configure nxlog to remove a file after processing, as opposed to setting a time interval of 1 second like above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See the [response](https://nxlog.co/question/1455/unable-fileremove-linux-setup) in the NXLog forums.